# Use the DGPS of iPhone and Android

Tags: android, iphone, gps

I'm working on a robot which need to know its exact position (with an error of +/- 5cm) in relation to a given point of coordinates (0, 0). So my question is :

> Is it possible to get this kind of precision using differential GPS ?

The idea would be to place a GPS at the position (0, 0) and a GPS on the robot to compute the difference of coordinates of the 2 GPS and get the relative position of the robot.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: GPS will not be precies enough, it about 3 meter but mostly more.

Comment: If you think about, differential GPS cannot be more accurate than any single fix.  Motion sensing is probably more accurate.

Comment: @rckoenes, do you think computing the difference between the coordinates of the GPS of 2 iPhone will be more precies ?

Comment: @LucasWillems No, GPS by it self is to inaccurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible with DGPS, but bot in an mobile phone.
Precision Farming use GPS with cm accuracy.

With a consumer GPS if you would be able to read out the Satellite RAW data, you could do a GPS Post processing, that way you could reach <1m accuracy.

for cm accuracy you need 2 Phase Gps receiver (conusmer ois 1 -phase),
and additional RTK, Then you have cm accuracy.

Read more by searching for topic RTK, Rinex, GPS Post processing.
(But it is not possible for current mobile phones, using GPS)
And robotoers often want to work indoors, where GPS doesn not work, too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know Phase Gps and RTK GPS. Do you what will be the price of system using "2 Phase Gps receiver and additional RTK" ?

Comment: 2 phase GPS: 2000 - 3000$, consider upvoting if you got usefull info: RTK: I dont know, some contracts are by seconds you use RTK.

Answer (score 0):

No, GPS is way too inaccurate for that. Best guess would be that you can use the accelerometer to calculate a relative distance on movement.

Answer (score 0):

Might be placing 3 wifi routers in the field and compute by using their relatively signal strength would give a better appoximation on the robot's current location?